# MySQL won't start in CentOS 5.5 and the "ERROR 2002"

Tags: mysql, selinux, mysql-error-2002

I would like to ask a help for the problem I encountered. My mysql server suddenly stopped after I install php-soap. I don't know why it get stopped actually...

Since it's stopped I tried to start it by typing the line:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

After this, I get this message:

```
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

Starting mysql seems failed. Since I tried it numerous times and got this result a numerous time. I checked the mysqlog and here's what I got.

==== MYSQL LOG ====

```
120511 21:34:43 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
120511 21:34:43 [ERROR] Error message file '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys' had only 481 error messages,
but it should contain at least 641 error messages.
Check that the above file is the right version for this program!
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Unknown error 1146
120511 21:34:43 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120511 21:34:43  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
120511 21:34:44  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120511 21:34:44  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
120511 21:34:44 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

**Other infos:**

**OS**: CentOS 5.5 64bit

**Mysql Version:** Sorry I couldn't get the version of mysql installed on my server due this error I am getting:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Can somebody help me to resolve this problem?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your installation of mysql is not corrupt with /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys having been modified to contain less than the number of entries needed.

i would get the installation/src files for mysql for your centos box again.  Untar it and locate the file errmsg.sys from sql/share/english, copy it to /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys and restart your mysqld.    Another option is just to reinstall mysql from centos repo, after backing up your dbs to make sure they don't get blown away and to have a copy/backup of it.

I would also find out what made the changes to the errmsg.sys file.

Comment: I would like to try fixing it without re-installing mysql (re-installing mysql would be my last resort).

Comment: then get the source tarball, untar it, and just copy the errmsg.sys from the original src to the /usr/share/mysql/english .  make sure the src file is the same version as the msyql install on your centos.   The errmsg.sys from source for your version of mysql should contain the full errmsg.sys